# emacs search and replace with regular expressions

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

With emacs, how can I search and replace regular expressions within a buffer?  How can I do this programmatically by evaluating elisp in addition to interactively? For example, replace one or more spaces with tabs, where I need to match `' +'` (one or more spaces) with something like `C-q-TAB`. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe the `replace-regexp` docstring used to have an Elisp snippet showing how to do it programmatically, but I'm not at my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically you can do it as follows:

```
(defun region-replace-multiple-spaces-with-single-space(beg end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region beg end)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward-regexp " +" nil t)
    (replace-match " " nil nil)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is `M-x replace-regexp`

Comment: Also try `M-x query-replace-regexp`, unfortunately bound by default to the awkward key combination `C-M-%`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a multi-purpose `replace-regexp`:

- if region is active, replace regexp in region
- with numeric argument, call `query-replace-regexp`
- otherwise, replace regexp on current line (actually very useful)

Here's the code:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'replace-regexp-dwim)

(defun replace-regexp-dwim (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (destructuring-bind (from to &rest)
      (query-replace-read-args "Replace regexp" nil)
    (if arg
        (query-replace-regexp from to)
      (let ((st (if (region-active-p)
                    (region-beginning)
                  (line-beginning-position)))
            (en (if (region-active-p)
                    (region-end)
                  (line-end-position))))
        (goto-char st)
        (while (re-search-forward from en t)
          (replace-match to nil t))))))
```